# Second join Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

My function in model looks like:

```
public function join($table, $select, $join, $on, $join2 = FALSE, $on2 = FALSE, $where = FALSE, $single = FALSE, $order = FALSE, $sort = FALSE, $limit = FALSE)
{   
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->join($join, $on);

    if($join2 == TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->join($join2, $on2);
    }
    if($where == TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
    }

    if($order == TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->order_by($order, $sort);
    }

    if($limit == TRUE)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, 0);
    }

    if($single == TRUE)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['users'] = $this->users_m->get('users');

    $join = "blog_list";
    $on = "blog_list.id_p = users.id";
    $join2 = "meeting_list";
    $on2 = "meeting_list.id_p = users.id";
    $data['join'] = $this->users_m->join('users', 'users.id, users.nickname, blog_list.cat2, meeting_list.id_m', $join, $on, $join2, $on2, FALSE, FALSE, 'nickname', 'desc');

    $this->load->view('admin/users/index', $data);
}
```

And view:

```
<?php foreach($join as $row): ?>
    <?php echo ($row->id); ?> 
    <?php echo ($row->nickname); ?> 
    <?php echo ($row->cat2); ?> 
    <?php echo ($row->id_m); ?> 
    <br>
```

And problem is with second join (when i use $join2), it means when i echo $row->id the id comes from table in $join2 instead from $table. When i use onle one join everything works when i specify in $select that id is from 'user'(users.id) but with second join it wont works. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editting your select in this way that you select fields by name and then assign them to another name. So, par example:

```
public function index()
{
   //Other code
    $data['join'] = $this->users_m->join('users', 'users.id as uid, users.nickname, blog_list.cat2, meeting_list.id_m', $join, $on, $join2, $on2, FALSE, FALSE, 'nickname', 'desc');

   //Other code
}
```

Now echo :

```
<?php echo ($row->uid); ?>
```

Comment: Do a print_r of your row and see whats in it.